# How to get rid off special character showing up for "utf-8" command in csv

Tags: python, utf-8, web-scraping

Running my spider I can see results with special character in csv file. I could understand that it is the side-effect of using utf-8. Is there any workaround to get rid of those signs. here is the partial picture of that results.

Code to print the results:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

def Startpoint(mpage):
    global writer
    outfile=open('NZLDATA.csv','w', newline='', encoding='utf8')
    writer=csv.writer(outfile)
    page=1
    while page<=mpage:
        address = "https://www.katalystbusiness.co.nz/business-profiles/bindex"+str(page)+".html"
        tail="https://www.katalystbusiness.co.nz/business-profiles/"
        response = requests.get(address)
        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        titles = tree.xpath('//p/a/@href')
        for title in titles:
            if "bindex" not in title and "cdn-cgi" not in title:
                fullad = tail + title
                Endpoint(fullad)

        page+=1

def Endpoint(address):
    global writer
    page = requests.get(address)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles=tree.xpath('//div[@id="content"]')
    for title in titles:
        try:
            Name = title.xpath('.//p/text()')[0]
            Add1 = title.xpath('.//p/text()')[2]
            Add2 = title.xpath('.//p/text()')[4]
            Add3 = title.xpath('.//p/text()')[7]
            Add4 = title.xpath('.//p/text()')[9]
            Add5 = title.xpath('.//p/text()')[11]
            Add6 = title.xpath('.//p/a/@href')[0]
        except:
            continue
        popdata=(Name, Add1, Add2, Add3, Add4, Add5, Add6)
        print(popdata)
        writer.writerow(popdata)

Startpoint(2)
```

Image of the output:
[image]

Comment: How do you produce the CSV output? With a print expression?

Comment: The problem is apparently that you are encoding too early: with `.encode('utf-8')`, you convert the data to `bytes`, but whatever method writes out the data is expecting strings, thus it calls `str()` on your `bytes` objects, which produces this representation form using the `b'...'` prefix notation. You should keep the data as strings and configure the output stream to use UTF-8 encoding instead.

Comment: Thanks sir lenz for your response. gonna edit the post as you asked for.

Comment: Although I accepted the answer as it was working for a string if tried in the idle. But in this case replacing with those characters make the csv output blank. thanks for your concern, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to fix things:

Don't encode individual strings. Instead, specify the encoding when opening the output file, then pass strings to the CSV writer.

In the Startpoint function, write:

```
...
outfile = open('NZLand.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8')
...
```

In the Endpoint function, omit all the `.encode("utf-8")` method calls.

#### Explanation:

If you encode the individual strings, they become `bytes` objects.
When you pass those to `print()` or the CSV writer (both of which expect strings, not bytes), they will be converted to strings again – but not by decoding them, but by producing the `repr` form, ie. they are shown with the notation used for writing `bytes` literals, using quotes with a "b" prefix (`b'...'`).

Comment: Btw: There's no need to declare `writer` global (which should be avoided whenever possible). Just pass it as a second argument to the Endpoint function.

Comment: I tried with your instruction sir, but I got an issue. Only the last column that means the column with "web address" are getting filled in with fresh data as i expected but the rest columns are blank.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with encoding. Most probably, the corresponding nodes in the documents are empty.

Comment: Thanks sir lenz for your answer. If corresponding fields are empty then how come i get those data with funny characters when i remove the encoding from the line you suggested and place those where it was before cause you know if there is no data in those specified fields then the result should always be empty be it for using encoding or not. Thanks again.

Comment: I see that most entries start with a newline character (`\n`). When you look at the CSV data in Excel, have you verified that the cells are actually empty, or if they just seem so because they start with a blank line? (Click into a cell and move the down arrow.)

Comment: Love you very much sir, lenz. This is exactly what you thought. This is the answer I was expecting and it solves my problem. By the way, can i accept your answer withdrawing the earlier one.

Comment: One more thing: should i fix that new line thing in csv manually after it has done scraping?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. For the newlines, I suggest adding `.strip()` where you had `.encode('utf-8')` before. This will remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Now it works the way I expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

For any string with funny characters you don't like, you can just `replace` them:

```
s = "b'\nthis here'"
print s.replace('b','').replace('\n','').replace('\'','')
```

Result:

```
this here
```

Comment: Thanks JacobIRR for your answer. At least your answer shows me how should my next step be. So, the bottom line is that replacing is all I got at this moment.

Comment: This will unconditionally replace every occurrence of 'b' also inside the string, not only the literal prefix. Also, you remove actual newlines (`\n`), but not what is in the OP's output: a backslash followed by the letter *n*.